# Can running for 20 minutes on your rest day prevent muscle growth?

Tags: workout-routines

So I am doing this workout-

[image: workout]

So I am a bit skinny and you have to do this 4 times a week to gain muscles. And so you have to keep 1 day off between 2 workout to let the muscles heal.

But at the same time I have a small belly and I want to get rid of it. So from today I started running in the morning with an empty belly(without eating anything) for 20 minutes. Should I restrict this running too to 4 day a week? Does running prevent the muscles from regenerating?

Or should I run everyday and running doesn't count as an exercise on my rest day?

Comment: Do you do all those exercises? What is your rep scheme? Can you improve the formatting of your post please.

Comment: @JJosaur sorry about that! So the idea is, you chose 2-3 exercises from every subject and then take 1-2 subject everyday and do 4 sets of 8-12 reps of every exercise. You gotta do the workout 4 days a week and finish all the subjects at least more than once per week

Comment: FYI, that workout program is all over the place in terms of ability scaling, pull ups will develop your back much more than push-ups. Calisthenics should be balanced in terms of work output to ensure your body stays 'balanced' in its muscle growth

Answer (score 1):

Does cardio impair muscle gains?

Maybe. The adaptions from strength training verses cardiovascular activity to conflict to a extent. ([1](http://journals.lww.com/acsm-msse/Abstract/2006/11000/Concurrent_Strength_and_Endurance_Training__From.13.aspx))([2](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17095927)) You cannot be an elite bodybuilder AND an elite marathoner. The ultimate answer depends on your training status and the modality, volume, intensity, and timing of your endurance and strength work ([3](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22002517)).

**If general health and fitness is your main goal**, then including both forms of exercise is a good move. If maximizing muscle gain at the expense of all else is your primary concern, then endurance work should be minimized or eliminated entirely.

Also, see this question: [What effect does restricted oxygen in cardio have on muscle damage & repair?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/18408/what-effect-does-restricted-oxygen-in-cardio-have-on-muscle-damage-repair)

Comment: well I want to lose my belly fat too..so can't I do running and strength exercises at the same time?

Comment: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/869/what-exercises-should-i-perform-to-reduce-fat-on-a-specific-area-of-my-body do both. I run around 15k total in a week and I do a workout (crossfit) 5 days a week (excluding runs). Broscience: Running kick-started my weight loss after I stalled at 80kg. I'm now at 75kg and am lifting weight at a intermediate level.

Comment: but I want to gain weight and at the same time lose belly fat..

Comment: Then eat at a maintenance of calories. You can do this but it is easier IMO to lose weight first and then eat to gain muscle afterwards.